# Adding variable name instead of value of variable to select list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html-select

I'm trying to add new options to the select tag, but my code is adding the variable name addedFont instead of the actual number (i.e. 20 pixels)

**main.js**

```
$("#add-font-size").click(function(){
    var addedFont = $("#fontSizeInput").val();
    $("#font-select").append("<option value = addedFont> addedFont pixels </option>");
});
```

**index.html**

```
<select class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="font-select">
    <option value="16" selected>16 pixels</option>
    <option value="17">17 pixels</option>
    <option value="18">18 pixels</option>
    <option value="19">19 pixels</option>
    <option value="20">20 pixels</option>
</select>
```

**Selector's options after adding font size 21:**

[image]

Comment: Assuming `addedFont` is a variable `'<option value="'+addedFont+'"> addedFont pixels </option>'`

Comment: a simple correction `'<option value = "'+addedFont+'">'+ addedFont+' pixels </option>'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use string concatenation.

```
$("#font-select").append('<option value="'+addedFont+'">' + addedFont + 'pixels </option>');
```

However, I would recommend you to create element using jQuery

```
$("#font-select").append($('<option>', {value : addedFont, text:addedFont + " pixels"});
```

Comment: Neat strategy. Just would like to add that I think OP meant `addedFont + ' pixels'` for the text, rather than the literal `'addedFont pixels'`.

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation (`+`) is what you were looking for here.

```
 $("#font-select").append("<option value=\"" + addedFont + "\">" + addedFont + " pixels </option>");
```

However, in the spirit of [other clever answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42501888/7256039), I would like to introduce the surprisingly simple syntax `new Option(text, value)` which has [excellent browser support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLOptionElement/Option):

```
$('#font-select').append(new Option(addedFont + ' pixels', addedFont))
```

### Demo:

```js
$('#add-font-size').click(function () {
  var addedFont = $('#fontSizeInput').val()
  $('#font-select').append(new Option(addedFont + ' pixels', addedFont))
})
```

```css
#fontSizeInput { width: 5em; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="custom-select mb-2 mr-sm-2 mb-sm-0" id="font-select">
    <option value="16" selected>16 pixels</option>
    <option value="17">17 pixels</option>
    <option value="18">18 pixels</option>
    <option value="19">19 pixels</option>
    <option value="20">20 pixels</option>
</select>


<!-- Demo Code -->
<hr>
<p><input id="fontSizeInput" type="number" value="21"> px</p>
<button id="add-font-size">Add Font Size</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are enclosing the variable inside the double quotes so it is treated as a string not a variable, use like this

```
$("#font-select").append("<option value = "' + addedFont + '">" + addedFont + " pixels </option>");
```